# Blank Screen on Windows XP SP3 Installation

Tags: windows-xp

After installing Windows XP SP3 (upgrading from SP2), it shows a blank screen - rather than any login.  I can login via safe mode (with networking), but not during normal settings.  Anyone see this - this feels like it may be a common issue with SP3.

Comment: Were you using a custom [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Identification_and_Authentication) prior to the upgrade?

Comment: Have you checked all the drivers in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this exact same issue and so have many other people. To fix it i had to [uninstall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950249) the update, restart the machine and re-install and this fixed the issue